# RegEx for validating a URL with optional ports

Tags: regex

I am trying to get this regex dialed-in to validate whether a URL begins with https and if a port is supplied the only valid values are 443 or 5443. This regex is pretty close but not quite there.

```
^(https:\/\/)([a-zA-Z\d\.]{2,})\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})(:5{0,1}443)?(.)*
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mainstream URL validator that tests if it's between whitespace boundary's.
It only allows https device and the port numbers 5443 or 443.

```
(?<!\S)https://(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::5?443)?(?:/[^\s]*)?(?!\S)
```

Readable version

```
 (?<! \S )

 https ://
 (?:
      \S+ 
      (?: : \S* )?
      @
 )?
 (?:
      (?:
           (?:
                [1-9] \d? 
             |  1 \d\d 
             |  2 [01] \d 
             |  22 [0-3] 
           )
           (?:
                \.
                (?: 1? \d{1,2} | 2 [0-4] \d | 25 [0-5] )
           ){2}
           (?:
                \.
                (?:
                     [1-9] \d? 
                  |  1 \d\d 
                  |  2 [0-4] \d 
                  |  25 [0-4] 
                )
           )
        |  (?:
                (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
           )
           (?:
                \.
                (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
           )*
           (?:
                \.
                (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,} )
           )
      )
   |  localhost
 )
 (?: : 5? 443 )?
 (?: / [^\s]* )?

 (?! \S )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append a `/` after this optional port group so it doesn't allow any digits before a `/`. Try using this regex,

```
^(https:\/\/)([a-zA-Z\d\.]{2,})\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})(:5?443)?\/\S*
```

Notice, I've also changed `(:5{0,1}443)?` to `(:5?443)?` and changed last `.*` to `\S*` so the url doesn't capture spaces as spaces in URL is not a valid thing. Besides that, you can also get rid of so many groups in your regex, unless you need them.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6KcN1n/1)**

**Edit:**

As you said in comments, that you want to match following URLs too,

```
https://example.com
https:example.com
https:example.com:443
```

you need to make `\/\S*` part optional by placing a `?` after them. The modified regex becomes this, which will match above URLs.

```
^https:\/\/([a-zA-Z\d\.]{2,})\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})(:5?443)?(\/\S*)?
```

**[Demo with filepath part being optional](https://regex101.com/r/6KcN1n/3)**

Comment: Thank you, Pushpesh. I removed the groupings as I don't need them. I am using this is the pattern ^https:\/\/[a-zA-Z\d\.]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(:5?443)?\/\S* but URLs like https://example.com https://www.example.com https://example.com:443 don't match. I am attempting to resolve that issue. Do you know how to cover these URLs as well?

Comment: @chad: Ok if you want them matched, let me make one part optional. Just few moments.

Comment: My apologies, Pushpesh. https is not optional. I didn't notice that it's being removed when I post the comment. Those URLs, with https, don't match.

Comment: @chad: Updated. Check now.

Comment: @pushpesh, this last edit appears to do the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help dear :)

Comment: I ended up back at this. The regex broke down with URLs that contained a domain/sub-domain with special characters e.g. https://abc-def.blah-blah.com/snuh.html.

Answer (score -1):

Your RegEx seems to work okay. You may try using [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/h6zyIO/1) and add additional boundaries, just for safety, if you wish so:

```
^(https:\/\/)([a-zA-Z\d\.]{2,})\.([a-zA-Z]{2,}):(5443|443)?$
```

[image]

I only added a <kbd>$</kbd> end char so that to bound your original expression from the right. You may just simply add a few port numbers, if you may have, in this capturing group:

```
(5443|443)
```

You can also remove unnecessary boundaries, if you wish.